# Skip Unneeded services in Ubuntu boot

Tags: network-manager, startup-applications

I wish to skip following services loading in the boot of my ubuntu machine and set up manually later after login in order to spped up startup.

1. All network related services(nmbd, network manager etc)
2. systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to disable services to not load during startup you need `systemctl`.

First list all the startup services using

```
systemctl
```

If you want to disable a service to run automatically at startup, use the command

```
sudo systemctl disable service_name
```

replace "service_name" with the service you want to disable at startup.

If you want the service enabled again, use the command

```
sudo systemctl enable service_name
```